# Why the barcode scanner code being used in google cloud print integration code?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-cloud-print

The Google cloud print integration code at https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android 
uses the zxing barcode scanner code as well. Please refer:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  if (url.startsWith(ZXING_URL)) {
    Intent intentScan = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intentScan.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    try {
      startActivityForResult(intentScan, ZXING_SCAN_REQUEST);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException error) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
    }
  } else {
    view.loadUrl(url);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

If the url starts with an ZXING zxing:// it tries to scan the current document for the existance of a QR code, if it exists, load the url and then load it into the view.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages

But that is only for pages that start with zxing://

Comment: Not able to get the context of ZXing url for the case of Google cloud print.